# Не могу удалить подключение шрифта с веб

Tags: php, wordpress, шрифты

Привет!У меня есть сайт на WordPress и мне нужно подключить к нему шрифты.Вот как я это сделал(напишите если что то не по каноно):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    src: url("../fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.eot"),
    src: url("../fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
    src: url("../fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("../fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Но у меня в браузере находит подключение этого шрирфта с веб:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я захожу в свой header.php и у меня там нету подключения данного шрифта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Захожу в index.php и там его тоже нету:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="banner">
  <div class="banner-image">
      <?php if( get_field('des-off', 'options') == 'true' ):  
$image = get_field('desc-img', 'options');

if( !empty($image) ): 
$size = 'desctop';
    $thumb = $image['sizes'][ $size ];
    ?>

    <img class="dont-show hidden-xs" src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" />
   <?php endif; endif; ?>


<?php if( get_field('mob-off', 'options') == 'true' ):  
$image = get_field('mob-img', 'options');

if( !empty($image) ): 
$size = 'mobail';
    $thumb = $image['sizes'][ $size ];
    ?>
    <img class="mobi-logo hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" />
    <?php endif; endif; ?>
     <?php if( get_field('des-off', 'options') == 'true' ):  ?>  
    <div class="banner-title dont-show hidden-xs">
      <div class="banner-tbl dont-show">
        <div class="banner-td dont-show">
          <div class="container dont-show">
             <?php the_field('des-ban', 'options'); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if( get_field('mob-off', 'options') == 'true' ):  ?>  
    <!--mobil banner-->
    <div class="banner-title dont-show hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
      <div class="banner-tbl dont-show">
        <div class="banner-td dont-show">
          <div class="container dont-show mob-ban">
             <?php the_field('mob-ban', 'options'); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

    <!--Форма подписки после баннера-->
  <?php if( get_field('home-pdf2', 'options') == 'true' ): ?>  
  <div class="container dont-show">
    <div class="row product">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 cover">
            <img alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/book-cover-top.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 subscribe">
            <div style="font-family: 'PT Serif';">
            <?php the_field('home-pdf1', 'options'); ?>
                <div>
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="name" class="form-control input-lg" id="InputName" placeholder="<?php printf( _e( 'Your Name', 'zaxidna' )); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="InputEmail" placeholder="<?php printf( _e( 'E-mail', 'zaxidna' )); ?>">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg"><?php printf( _e( 'Get Now', 'zaxidna' )); ?></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<!--  END   Форма подписки после баннера-->

</div>

<div class="container mobi-bg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
      <nav class="categories hidden-xs">
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'categories', 'menu_class' => 'list-inline')); ?>
        <hr />
      </nav>
      <main id="book-form" class="content">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile;
?>
<nav>
<?php wpex_pagination(); ?>
</nav>
<?php

        else :
            get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>
      </main>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 side">
      <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" class="form-control" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php printf( _e( 'Search', 'zaxidna' )); ?>" />
          <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </div>
      </form>
     <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Можете подсказать как мне удалить это подключение шрифта и мешает ли оно моему подключению?Возможно это стандартная функция WP?

Answer (score 0):

В коде header.php у вас стоит `<?php wp_head();?>` это функция-хук, к нему могут цепляться разные плагины. Поищите в исходном коде по слову "wp_head". Нужен такой код add_action('wp_head', 'функция'); Так узнаете какая функция добавляет лишний код. Потом для этой функции указываете remove_action('wp_head', 'функция');

Answer (score 0):

Судя по коду, каким добавлен шрифт, он добавлен вашей темой zaxidna. И, скорее всего, в настройках темы есть есть поля, отвечающие за это. Ищите `fonts.googleapis.com` в файлах темы, в первую очередь, в functions.php

Поскольку вы используете phpStorm, это совсем просто - ctrl+shift+F в папке темы.